# why ffmpeg command producing error in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

After the installation i tried this command in terminal

```
ffmpeg
```

but i got error message like this

```
root@client85-desktop:~# ffmpeg
bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: cannot execute binary file
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path `/usr/local/bin/` indicates, that you have installed a **custom version** of ffmpeg. The version you have installed with `apt-get install` is located at `/usr/bin/` (without the "local" part). To execute the version apt-get has installed, run

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

You can remove `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` or mark it as non-exexcutable with `sudo chmod -x /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`. Run `hash -r` so the change takes effect in the current shell. Log out and log back in so that the change takes effect for every graphical application.

As soon as `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` has been treated with one of the above mentioned method, simply calling `ffmepg` will start the one at `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` by default.

**Edit** Added information from @Ramchandra_Apte on how to do this without a complete reboot.

Comment: Suggestion a reboot seems a bit overkill, simply opening a new shell should do it, right?

Comment: @user50849 You don't even need to reboot; simply run `hash -r`.

Comment: You mean "don't even need a new shell", I assume? Good to know, I didn't know what the command was to refresh the current environment, so I suggested a new shell, but `hash -r` is even better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah something isn't quite right here. If you install ffmpeg, its binary is installed to `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`, not `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`.

So the first assumption I have to make is either:

- You've installed a non-standard `ffmpeg` package
- Something else has included a weird local and broken copy of `ffmpeg` for some reason.

First see if `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` will run. If it does, at least you've probably got the proper ffmpeg installed and we can just focus on removing the dud copy. If you don't, you've gone and got yourself a dodgy copy.  I'm not you, I don't know what you've done but remove dodgy repositories and generally clean house.

Now let's see if there's a package associated with this `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` version

```
dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

That will either tell you it hasn't found anything or it will tell you which package it came from. If there's a package, `sudo dpkg -r <package name>` and try `ffmpeg` again.

If there's no package you're left in the unenviable spot of needing to manually remove it. If you've built this from source, you can cd into the source directory and run a `sudo make uninstall`. If you still claim not to know where this came from you can try a `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` but I can't say what effect that may have on other applications if this is something that they've done.